# cfml jquery uncaught syntax error invalid token?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

A question mark shows up at the top of the page but I can't find it.  I'm simply trying to send a test email from a batch of emails to verify the content.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function() {
        $("#message_submit").live('click', function() {
            alert('x');
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'GET',
                  url: 'cfc/basic.cfc?method=SendTestEmail',
                  data: 'EmailAddress=' + $("#previewemailaddress").text() + '&emailbody=' + $("#Email_Text").text() + '&emailfrom=' + $("#email_from").text(),
                  error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // show error
                    alert(errorThrown);
                  },
                  success: function () {
                    return true;
                  }
                });
         return false;
        });
    });​
)};
```

```
<table width="900">
  <tr>
    <td width="900"><cftextarea name="Email_Text" id="Email_Text" value="#Qmailer.Email_Text#"  richtext="True"></cftextarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <p><label for="previewemailaddress">Email Address for test email</label><input type="text" size="30" name="previewemailaddress" id="previewemailaddress" /></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Send Test Email" name="commit" id="message_submit"/></p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your last line should be `});` instead of `)};`.

A bit of an explanation: the error has nothing to do with jQuery. What you had there is an invalid JavaScript syntax. In the future just open your browser's JavaScript console to check for errors.

You can have a look at it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9mdNb/).

Comment: I'm trying to use Chrome and the tools don't make sense yet.  The console is where I got the error message.  Changing the ending syntax didn't make any difference.

Comment: It worked when I found hidden characters in my editor that was causing the question mark at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You ending tag for your DOM ready event was a illegal character.. Try removing that

```
    });
    });​

 });  < -----
```

Your code was ending with  `)};`

Also check what error you see in the console section of your browser

Comment: I don't see an invalid character.

Comment: By illegal I meant you are not closing your braces properly.. wrong syntax